# Linked List , not sure where i am going wrong here,

Tags: java

My main class is at very bottom, i am   trying add nodes in to a list and display them like spcfied in the main class

```
        lList - print linkedlist: 
        lList.size() - print linkedlist size: 1
        lList.size() - print linkedlist size: 1
        lList - print linkedlist:
```

My list wont display, can someone point whats wrong

```
      public interface ListInterface {
       //List operations
        public boolean isEmpty();
        public int size();
        public void add(int index, Object item);
        public void remove(int index);
        public void removeAll();
            }// end interface
```

---

```
    public class Node {
Object item;
Node next;

Node(Object newItem) {
    item = newItem;
    next = null;

}

Node(Object newItem, Node nextNode) {
    item = newItem;
    next = nextNode;
}
public void setItem(Object newItem) {
        item = newItem;
      } // end setItem

public Object getItem() {
        return item;
      } // end getItem

public void setNext(Node nextNode) {
        next = nextNode;
      } // end setNext

public Node getNext() {
        return next;
      } // end getNext
     // end class Node
    }
```

---

```
 public class ListReferencedBased implements ListInterface {

private Node head;
private int numItems;


public ListReferencedBased(){
    numItems = 0;
    head = null;
}


@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return numItems == 0;
}



public int size() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return numItems;
}

private Node find(int index){
    Node curr = head;
    for(int skip = 0;skip < index;skip++){
        curr = curr.next;
    }
    return curr;

}

public void add(int index, Object item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(index == 0 && index < numItems + 1){
        if(index ==0){
            // insert in begning
            Node newNode = new Node(item, head);
            head = newNode;
        }
            else{
                Node prev = find(index - 1);

                Node newNode = new Node(item,prev.next);
                prev.next = newNode;
            }
            numItems++;
        }
    }




@Override
public void remove(int index) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (index == 0){
        head = head.next;
    }
    else{
        Node prev = find(index -1);

        Node curr = prev.next;
        prev.next = curr.next;
    }
    numItems--;
}


@Override
public void removeAll() {
    head = null;
    numItems = 0;



}
public String toString() {
    Node crunchifyCurrent = head.getNext();
    String output = "";
    while (crunchifyCurrent != null) {
        output += "[" + crunchifyCurrent.toString() + "]";
        crunchifyCurrent = crunchifyCurrent.getNext();
    }
    return output;
}
}
```

---

```
public class Nodemain {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
            ListReferencedBased lList = new ListReferencedBased();

            // add elements to LinkedList
            lList.add(0,"1");
            lList.add(1,"2");
            lList.add(2,"3");
            lList.add(3,"4");
            lList.add(4,"5");

            /*
             * Please note that primitive values can not be added into LinkedList
             * directly. They must be converted to their corresponding wrapper
             * class.
             */

            System.out.println("lList - print linkedlist: " + lList);
            System.out.println("lList.size() - print linkedlist size: " + lList.size());
       //   System.out.println("lList.get(3) - get 3rd element: " + lList.get(3));
        //    System.out.println("lList.remove(2) - remove 2nd element: " + lList.remove(2));
    //        System.out.println("lList.get(3) - get 3rd element: " + lList.get(3));
            System.out.println("lList.size() - print linkedlist size: " + lList.size());
            System.out.println("lList - print linkedlist: " + lList);
        }
}
```

Comment: If you only have one element then `head.getNext()` returns `null`.

Comment: your add method is flawed. only the first index will modify the list...

Comment: but i added 5 elements, .add(0,"1")

Comment: @UmNyobe how do i get the rest of the elements to add? what modification should i make to my add method

Comment: `add` only does something if index is 0.  Otherwise it does nothing. What were you trying to accomplish with the first `if` statement?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your print is calling toString on Node which will just print the address of Node, not what you want.   You need to have a toString method that will return the value in the node in order to display the list properly.

Second, your design may be specified by the teacher, but it's silly to specify adding to a list by position.  At the very least, providing addLast and addFirst methods will make it a lot easier to do what you obviously want to do, which is build a list.

In this case, I assume you want addLast because you want to build the list in order.
This is going to be very inefficient because you have to scan through the entire list each time to deposit a new element at the end but presumably that's the assignment.

Start by cleaning up your API if you can.  Write addLast that adds the element to the end.  Then repost the code if you still have a problem.  You really shouldn't be tracking the position to add a value to the end.

Comment: No, the "one too far" is not the problem.  Note that when he calls `add`, he calls it with index 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.

Comment: so I need a second ADD method that only inserts the first node? and than use the ADD i alreaddy created to do the rest like elemented at index 1,2,3,4?

Comment: ajb is correct.  Your add function itself has a problem.  You have some weird logic in there.   What do you want to do?  If index = 0, add at the front, right?  And if index is anything else, add where?